# What's the best way to add a full screen background image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to add a full-screen image to the View so I write this code

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('image!egg')}  style={styles.backgroundImage}/>
    </View>
)
```

and defined the style as

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
     flexDirection: 'column',
},
     backgroundImage:{
     width:320,
     height:480,
   }
...
```

but in this way how am I supposed to find the actual iPhone screen size?

I've seen an API to access the Pixel Density but nothing about the screen size...

Any idea?

Comment: How about performance? Is it ok to use `.png` or `.jpg`? Is ok to store wallpaper image inside app directory tree? Or is it better to use something else? `.svg` or anything?

Comment: @Sabito 錆兎standswithUkraine The criterion of React Native is pivotal to the question. so it belongs in the title.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use `flex: 1` styling on an `<Image>` element to have it fill the whole screen. You can then use one of the Image resize modes to have the image completely fill the element:

```
<Image source={require('image!egg')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
```

Style:

```
import React from 'react-native';

let { StyleSheet } = React;

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  }
});
```

I'm pretty sure you can get rid of the `<View>` wrapping your image and this will work.

Comment: Yup, it works, I've moved the Image element as top most and set its style as    `backgroundImage:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: Image.resizeMode.contain,
  },` Thanks

Comment: After struggling with this for a while I found it easiest to wrap the `Image` component in an absolutely positioned `View` to allow the background image to appear behind other content on the screen.

Comment: Important edit: `<Image src=...>` is now `<Image source=...>`

Comment: Now that z-index is supported, would you change this answer?

Comment: It is fine but the image is stretching and scroll is enabled in screen

Comment: How about performance? Is it ok to use `.png` or `.jpg`? Is ok to store wallpaper image inside app directory tree? Or is it better to use something else? `.svg` or anything?

Comment: @Green https://medium.com/reactnative/background-images-in-react-native-191f3ed95a45

Comment: can you use @media queries to change image depending on the scroll?

Answer (score 198):

**(This has been deprecated now you can use [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground))**

This is how I've done it. The main deal was getting rid of the static fixed sizes.

```
class ReactStrap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={require('image!background')} style={styles.container}>
        ... Your Content ...
      </Image>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // remove width and height to override fixed static size
    width: null,
    height: null,
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be done by docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: Thank you!
Make sure the `Image` is your first component returned, the container. At first, I accidently nested the `Image` within a `View` that was the container.

Comment: Does this work with https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html as content. Doesn't work for me, tabs are not clickable

Comment: Id like to have the whole app (Or Navigator) wrapped inside but its not working...

Comment: Changing 'resizeMode' to 'stretch' didn't work!
This worked like charm!!

Comment: YellowBox.js:76 Using <Image> with children is deprecated and will be an error in the near future. Please reconsider the layout or use <ImageBackground> instead.      When I add contents to <Image>, this warning shows up. it's really annoying.

Comment: this is actually deprecated. Use ImageBackground or (best) position:absolute

Comment: How about performance? Is it ok to use `.png` or `.jpg`? Is ok to store wallpaper image inside app directory tree? Or is it better to use something else? `.svg` or anything?

Answer (score 45):

***Note: This solution is old. Please refer to* https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting instead**

Try this solution. It is officially supported. I have just tested it and works flawlessly.

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
  }
});
```

And as for using it as Background image, just do the following.

```
<Image style={styles.backgroundImage}>
  <View>
    <Text>All your stuff</Text>
  </View>
</Image>
```

Comment: What the, is this officially supported?

Comment: Yes. It is.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: Whats the use of ```alignSelf``` and ```width``` here?

Comment: You are stretching <Image /> to the width available  and width needs to have null in order for 'stretch' to work

Comment: FYI, Image components can't have children in the latest version of React (0.51.0).  This no longer works.

Comment: I will check and respond. Thanks though.

Answer (score 30):

### Update March 2018 Using Image is deprecated use ImageBackground

```
  <ImageBackground 
          source={{uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/89432/pexels-photo-89432.jpeg?h=350&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb'}}
          style={{ flex: 1,
            width: null,
            height: null,
            }}
        >
       <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Your Contents</Text>
       </View>

 </ImageBackground >
```

Comment: Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: This is correct, now you have to use ImageBackground, Image as a container is deprecated. View as a container here is not required you can use just ImageBackground as the main container.

Answer (score 21):

I tried several of these answers to no avail for android using react-native version = 0.19.0.

For some reason, the resizeMode inside my stylesheet did not work appropriately? However, when sytlesheet had

```
backgroundImage: {
flex: 1,
width: null,
height: null,
}
```

and, within the Image tag I specified the resizeMode:

```
<Image source={require('path/to/image.png')} style= {styles.backgroundImage} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.sretch}>
```

It worked perfectly! As mentioned above, you can use Image.resizeMode.cover or contain as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE to ImageBackground**

Since using `<Image />` as a container is deprecated for a while, all answers actually miss something important. For proper use choose `<ImageBackground />` with `style` **and** `imageStyle` prop. Apply all Image relevant styles to `imageStyle`.

For example:

```
<ImageBackground
    source={yourImage}
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#fc0',
      width: '100%', // applied to Image
      height: '100%' 
    }}
    imageStyle={{
      resizeMode: 'contain' // works only here!
    }}
>
    <Text>Some Content</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js

Answer (score 13):

Based on [Braden Rockwell Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827338/braden-rockwell-napier)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122285/471840), I made this `BackgroundImage` component

*BackgroundImage.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'

class BackgroundImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const {source, children, style, ...props} = this.props
    return (
      <Image source={ source }
             style={ { flex: 1, width: null, height: null, ...style } }
             {...props}>
        { children }
      </Image>
    )
  }
}
BackgroundImage.propTypes = {
  source: React.PropTypes.object,
  children: React.PropTypes.object,
  style: React.PropTypes.object
}
export default BackgroundImage
```

*someWhereInMyApp.js*

```
 import BackgroundImage from './backgroundImage'
 ....
 <BackgroundImage source={ { uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png" } }>
    <Text>Test</Text>
 </BackgroundImage>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use it as a background image, you will need to use the new `<ImageBackground>` component [introduced at the end of June 2017](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.46.0) in v0.46. It supports nesting while `<Image>` soon won't.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/9637dd4a1b78d5f6da510b1b4ad10d45d67badbf) summary:

> We are removing support of nesting views inside  component. We decided to do this because having this feature makes supporting
>   `intrinsinc content size` of the `<Image>` impossible; so when the
>   transition process is complete, there will be no need to specify image
>   size explicitly, it can be inferred from actual image bitmap.
>
> And this is the step #0.
>
> is very simple drop-in replacement which implements
>   this functionality via very simple styling. Please, use
>    instead of  if you want to put something
>   inside.

Answer (score 11):

Oh God Finally I find a great way for React-Native V 0.52-RC and native-base:

Your Content Tag Should be something like this:
//==============================================================

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground
        source={require('./../assets/img/back.jpg')}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <Text>
            Some text here ...
        </Text>
    </ImageBackground>
</Content>
```

And Your essential style is :
//==============================================================

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
backgroundImage:{
    flex : 1,
    width : '100%'
}
```

It works fine friends ... have fun

Comment: Hi, Just want to make sure ImageBackground where is that imported from?

Comment: OK so ImageBackground I imported from react-native however, I can not set with:100%

Comment: Did you ever run into an issue where it displays on Android Emulator but not on the device?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer , you can Import ImageBackground from React Native:
import {ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

witch device did you test?
I didn't find any problem on device.

Comment: My Emulator was a Nexus 5 specs. And my android was Wileyfox Swift. The main difference was the resolution so I checked it on the image and seems like if the image resolution is higher then your device it does not show. I tried making the image smaller with styles but did not work so I changed resolution on image lower and now it seems to work fine on. The resolution being lower wasn't really an issue cause it is a login screen and there are some text inputs and buttons on it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

```
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native";
<ImageBackground
     style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
     source={require('../assets/backgroundLogin.jpg ')}> //path here inside
    <Text>React</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 5):

For me this works fine, I used ImageBackground to set background image:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <View style={styles.container}> 
      <ImageBackground source={require('./Assets.xcassets/AppBackGround.imageset/2x.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Marketing at the speed of today</Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont Segoe UI",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  title:{
    color: "#9A9A9A",
    fontSize: 24,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since 0.14 this method won't work, so I built a static component that will make this simple for you guys.  You can just paste this in or reference it as a component.

This should be re-useable and it will allow you to add additional styles and properties as-if it were a standard `<Image />` component

```
const BackgroundImage = ({ source, children, style, ...props }) => {
  return (
      <Image
        source={source}
        style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null, ...style}}
        {...props}>
        {children}
      </Image>
  );
}
```

just paste this in and then you can use it like image and it should fit the entire size of the view it is in (so if it's the top view it will fill your screen.

```
<BackgroundImage source={require('../../assets/backgrounds/palms.jpg')}>
    <Scene styles={styles} {...store} />
</BackgroundImage>
```

[Click here for a Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekpAl.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

**Latest as of Oct'17** **(RN >= .46)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  ...
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

render() {
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={require('path/to/img')} style={styles.urStyle}>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Answer (score 3):

To handle this use case, you can use the `<ImageBackground>` component, which has the same props as `<Image>`, and add whatever children to it you would like to layer on top of it.

Example:

```
return (
  <ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

For more: [ImageBackground | React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground)

> Note that you must specify some width and height style attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure your Image has resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} or {Image.resizeMode.stretch} and set image style width to null

```
<Image source={CharacterImage} style={{width: null,}} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The width and height with value null doesn't work for me, then I thought to use top, bottom, left, and right position and it worked.
Example:

```
bg: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
},
```

And the JSX:

```
<Image style={styles.bg} source={{uri: 'IMAGE URI'}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

(RN >= .46)

> the  component cannot contain children if you want to render content on top of the image, consider using absolute positioning.

or you can use ***ImageBackground***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { 
  ...
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

render() {
  return (
    
  <ImageBackground source={require('path/to/img')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} />
      <View style={{flex: 3,backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} >
  </ImageBackground>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to implemet background:

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={require('../../images/screen_login.jpg')}>
  <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
    <Image style={styles.logo}
      source={require('../../images/logo.png')}
    />
  </View> 
  <View style={styles.containerTextInput}>
    < LoginForm />
  </View>   
</ImageBackground>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    //   backgroundColor:"#0984e3"
  },
  containerTextInput: {
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  logoContainer: {
    marginTop: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  logo: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a background image you can do so by using  but first you have to import this from 'react-native' as follows:

```
import {ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
```

then:

```
    export default function App() {
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>

            <ImageBackground source={require('./path/to/yourimage')} style={styles.backgroungImage}>
                <View style={styles.container}>Hello world!
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroungImage: {
    flex: 1,
    maxWidth: '100%',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { 
  ...
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

render() {
  return (
    
  <ImageBackground source={require('path/to/img')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} />
      <View style={{flex: 3,backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} >
  </ImageBackground>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
    },
});
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

incase you didn't solve it yet, React Native v.0.42.0 have resizeMode

```
<Image style={{resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={require('..img.png')} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/IGlBYaC.jpg'}} style={s.backgroundImage} />
    );
  }
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
      flex: 1,
      width: null,
      height: null,
  }
});
```

You can try it at: https://sketch.expo.io/B1EAShDie (from: [github.com/Dorian/sketch-reactive-native-apps](https://github.com/Dorian/sketch-reactive-native-apps))

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your image as a container:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Image
            source={require('./images/background.png')}
            style={styles.container}>
            <Text>
              This text will be on top of the image
            </Text>
        </Image>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've heard about having to use BackgroundImage because in future you are supposed to not be able to nest the Image tag. But I could not get BackgroudImage to properly display my background. What I did was nest my Image inside a View tag and style both the outer View as well as the image. Keys were setting width to null, and setting resizeMode to 'stretch'. Below is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';

export default class BasicImage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {};
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <Image 
         source={this.props.source}
         style={styles.backgroundImage}
       />
      </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({   
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   width: null,
   height: null,
   marginBottom: 50
  },
    text: {
      marginLeft: 5,
      marginTop: 22,
      fontFamily: 'fontawesome',
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 25,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    },
  backgroundImage: {
   flex: 1,
   width: null,
   height: null,
   resizeMode: 'stretch',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ImageBackground>` as already said by **antoine129**. Using `<Image>` with children is deprecated now.

```
class AwesomeClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('image!background')} style={styles.container}>
        <YourAwesomeComponent/>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An another easy solution:

```
<Image source={require('../assets/background.png')}
      style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: -1}}/>

<View style={{flex: 1, position: 'absolute'}}>

  {/*rest of your content*/}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my background image issue using this code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Alert,ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

import { TextInput,Button,IconButton,Colors,Avatar } from 'react-native-paper';

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
       UsernameOrEmail  : '',
       Password : '',
     }
    render() {
      return (
             <ImageBackground  source={require('../assets/icons/background3.jpg')} style {styles.backgroundImage}>
              <Text>React Native App</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          );
    }
  }


    export default SignInScreen;

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     backgroundImage: {
      flex: 1,
      resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**ImageBackground might have limit**

> Actually, you can use  directly and it is not deprecated.

If you want to add Background Image in React Native and also wants to add other elements on that Background Image, follow the step below:

> 1. Create a Container View
> 2. Create an Image element with 100% width and height. Also resizeMode: 'Cover'
> 3. Create another View element under Image element with position: 'absolute'

This is the code I use:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import Screen from '../library/ScreenSize'

export default class MenuScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      header: null
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                resizeMode: "cover",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                opacity: 0.4
              }}
              source={require("../assets/images/menuBackgroundImage.jpg")}
            ></Image>

            <View style={{
                width: Screen.width,
                height: Screen.height * 0.55,
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0}}>
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 48
                }}>Glad to Meet You!</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Enjoy Coding....

Output:

[image: This is the output of my code.]