# How to stretch a static image as background in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to use a background image in my react native app,
the image is smaller than the screen, so I have to stretch it.

but it doesn't work if the image is **loaded from asset bundle**

```jsx
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  }
});

<Image source={require('image!background')} style={styles.bgImage}>
  <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    Welcome to React Native!
  </Text>
</Image>
```

it looks like this:

[image]

however, it works fine for a remote image, through `source={{uri: 'background-image-uri'}}`:

[image]

Comment: Try `resizeMode: 'cover'` ? refer to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From Github issue: [Image {require} is broken in React Native for Resizing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4598#issuecomment-162328501), you could try `<Image style={{width: null, height: null}}`, hope that facebook would fix it soon.

Comment: setting the width and height worked for me...background : {
    flex:1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode:'stretch'
  },

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it helped me to realize that resizeMode is actually a prop, I was treating it as a css property.

Answer (score 11):

The Image tag should generally not be treated as a container view.

Having an absolutely positioned wrapper containing your (stretched/contained) image appears to work well:

```js
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bgImageWrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0
    },
    bgImage: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "stretch"
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10
    }
});



<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={styles.bgImageWrapper}>
    <Image source={require('image!background')} style={styles.bgImage} />
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    Welcome to React Native!
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. And why `Image` should not be treated as a container, while the offical document suggests [Background Image via Nesting](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#background-image-via-nesting)?

Comment: You can now use ImageBackground as a container view: https://medium.com/@hklucher/how-to-use-an-imagebackground-in-react-native-515ee06a6b1f

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the `Dimensions` module to get the width of the screen and set your image's width style to that value:

```js
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

It also seems strange that a remote image works fine...you can try loading up a local static image with the `uri` syntax by using `source={{uri: 'local_image_file_name' isStatic: true}}`.

Comment: Thanks @dave, I think the [offical document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything) explains it, `require('image!x')` results in an object with fixed width & height (size of the image):  `{"__packager_asset":true,"isStatic":true,"path":"...","uri":"logo","width":591,"height":573}`. I'll try the `uri` form and let you know the result, thx!

Answer (score 3):

for me use `undefined` instead of `null` value. on typescript environment, it will be prompted not assignable

```
 bgImage: {
flex: 1,
width: undefined,
height: undefined,
resizeMode: 'stretch',
```

},