# react native background image

Tags: react-native, authentication, background-image

I need help. I want to add content on the below background image
This is my code :

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Image
                style={styles.mainContainer}
                source={require('../images/samples/login_bg.png')}>
                <LoginForm/>
                </Image>
            </View>
```

It shows me this error :

```
Error: The  component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using absolute positioning.
```

Comment: add mainconatiner style with the post

Answer (score 2):

From React Native Official Documentation:

> A common feature request from developers familiar with the web is
>   background-image. To handle this use case, you can use the
>    component, which has the same props as , and
>   add whatever children to it you would like to layer on top of it.
>
> You might not want to use  in some cases, since the
>   implementation is very simple. Refer to 's source
>   code for more insight, and create your own custom component when
>   needed.

```
return (
  <ImageBackground source={...}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

You can try

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ImageBackground
    style={styles.mainContainer}
    source={require('../images/samples/login_bg.png')}>
       <LoginForm/>
    </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks ,this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can, as you mentioned, position your image **absolute**ly in order to have all other items flexed within your container. By doing it like this, all of your other components will still follow all of your `flex` positioning styles, and the image would simply be in the background. Note: you must have the image defined first, as

> components are rendered in the order of definition.

This is the way id do it also, like so

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Image
       style={styles.mainContainer}
       source={require('../images/samples/login_bg.png')}>
    </Image>
    <LoginForm/>
</View>
```

and in styles (Note: this will place the image at the top left of the parent view)

```
mainContainer: {
    position: 'absolute'
    left: 0,
    top: 0
}
```

and then you can play around with the image dimensions, for example setting `width` to `Dimensions.get("window").width` would fill the screen horizontally. I believe you'd have to handle the stretch of the image, so have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273624/how-to-stretch-a-static-image-as-background-in-react-native)