# React-Native FullScreen Backaground Image

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, react-native

So, l have been trying for about 4 days, but l just can't seem to get an image to behave like it should in `flexbox`, especially with the `cover` resizeMode.

My code is:

```
var Creator = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return (
    <View style={ styles.container }>
      <Image source={ require('image!createBg') } style={ styles.image }></Image>
    </View>
  );
 }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }
});
```

and outputs with the following (the image is massively stretched instead of being 100% width):

[image: flexbox not working]

Any help would be appreciated, just can't see why its not working!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native

Comment: @boredgames tried that, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resizeMode` is a separate prop for the Image component, it has no effect inside the `style` prop. It also expects an enum from the Image component. So you should be using it like so:

```
<Image
 source={require('image!createBg')}
 style={styles.image}
 resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} />
```

Comment: Cheers dude. Also needed to add `alignItems: 'center'` to the container to make it work completely

Comment: Yup, glad to hear it worked for you. It seems like the answer in the question boredgames linked to is out of date. Not surprising given how rapidly the React Native API is changing.