# Full screen background image in React Native app

Tags: background-image, fullscreen, react-native

I'm trying to set a full background image on my login view.

I found that question here in Stackoverflow: [What's the best way to add a full screen background image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native/)

So I did it like there, but it didn't work:

[image]

```
var login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Image source={require('../images/login_background.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
        <View style={ styles.loginForm }>
          <Text>TEST</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  },

  loginForm: {
  },
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Here is the app, in case you guys want to take it a look -> [Full size background image example on rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/cm295Q). I don't know how to do it editable :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Wrap the `View`  with the `styles.loginForm`style inside the `Image` component

Comment: <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Image source={require('../images/login_background.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
              <View style={ styles.loginForm }>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
              </View>
            </Image>
          </View>

Like this, right?

It didn't work :/ -> http://puu.sh/mIZ9k/7df9341cd6.png

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try either of these two methods:

**The first** is similar to yours except you have `position: 'absolute'` on your login form:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
    },
    loginForm: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
});
```

The second method involves using the ImageView as a container:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Image source={require('../images/login_background.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
                <View style={ styles.loginForm }>
                    <Text>TEST</Text>
                </View>
            </Image>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the first method: http://puu.sh/mJ1xz/dc72257192.png

With the second: http://puu.sh/mJ1CK/493f68bb1c.png

Nothing worked :/

Comment: @JVLobo  I see you finally got it to work, if the answer worked for you, please mark accepted.

Comment: How about performance? Is it ok to use `.png` or `.jpg`? Or is it better to use something else?

Comment: I have added the width 100% to exact fit. Thank you.`  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
  },`

Comment: Also, I modified based on current work:<View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={backgroundImage} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <Text>TEST</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

Answer (score 29):

You should use ImageBackground component. [See React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

```
<ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: @WasanthaWijayaratna I am glad to help!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as this was built specially for the task in question, namely, to accept children

Answer (score 3):

I was doing a silly mistake...

**Text** component has a white background, and I thought the problem was with the **Image** and stuff...

So, the solution is to wrap the info inside the **Image** tag, as @Cherniv and @kamikazeOvrld said, but also set transparent background to the component inside it.

Here is the fully working example:

[image]

Code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  StatusBarIOS
} = React;

StatusBarIOS.setHidden(true);

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Image source={{uri: 'http://puu.sh/mJ1ZP/6f167c37e5.png'}} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
          <View style={ styles.loginForm }>
            <Text style={ styles.text }>Some text</Text>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  loginForm: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Also in [rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/M6RzMQ)

I hope it helps someone like me, when you are writing code all day, your brain doesn't work as well as you'd like!

Thanks.

Comment: How about performance? Is it ok to use `.png` or `.jpg`? Or is it better to use something else?

Comment: Hello I got bilowe error --> The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component or absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Umesh, the answer to your problem is already stated clearly.

The `<Image />` component does not contain any children component. What you need to do is to use the `<ImageBackground />` component as this will allow you embed other components inside it making them as children. So in your case you should do something like this

`<ImageBackground>
<Text>Write your text and some other stuffs here...</Text>
</ImageBackground>`

Note: Don't forget to add `flex: 1 or width`.

I hope my answer was clear enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <View style={styles.imageCancel}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(!this.state.visible) }}>
                 <Text style={styles.textCancel} >Close</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 imageCancel: {
         height: 'auto',
         width: 'auto',
         justifyContent:'center',
         backgroundColor: '#000000',
         alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
     textCancel: {
        paddingTop:25,
        paddingRight:25,
        fontSize : 18,
        color : "#ffffff",
        height: 50,
        },
 }};
```

[image]