# react native android background image is not fit to the screen

Tags: react-native

I am first at React native and I am trying to put an image as a background.
But I can't fit to the full-screen of my android devices. I tried with several android devices but not working for all.
here is my code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "cover",
    },
});

class MainMenuScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/img/main_menu/background.png')} style={styles.image}>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainMenuScreen;
```

And I also checked all articles from stackoverflow also.

[Full screen background image in React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992122/full-screen-background-image-in-react-native-app),

[What's the best way to add a full screen background image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native)

Those are what I tried.

And I will share the images what i have now.

[The screen of Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8WRl.png)

[The real image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c88Y6.png)

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <Image style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }}/>
           ......
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer but it is not solving my problem. Do you have any other solutions?