# Setting background image position (i.e. `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` in web)

Tags: react-native

When I have a background image:

```
<Image style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null, resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={require('../images/background.png')}>
    <!-- Children -->
</Image>
```

I am expecting my image to cover the entire screen while keeping the image's aspect ratio. (See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native) why I'm using `width: null, height: null`.)

However, if the image width is far smaller than the height, the image is *centered* which crops the top.

*Question:* How do I make the image start from the top instead, much like `background-position: 50% 0` would in the web?

Answer (score 1):

Hey:) Try increase height of your parent container ie.:

styles:

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    height: null,
    width: null,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    bottom: 0,
    flex: 1,
    height: '130%',
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
  },
})
```

component:

```
<View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={require('src/assets/images/background.jpg')}
          style={styles.image}
        />
      </View>
```

Using this solution you can a little manoeuvre your image.

Comment: Although Image is now deprecated for ImageBackground this can be updated into a good working example of how to reposition your background.