# How to set Image to take the full size screen with header in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I Have screen contain an image and I want to take the full-size screen with header?

I just use `position: "absolute"` but it's not working to wrap the header, and I can't use `header: null` because I want the back button to appear!

so how can I handle this?

what I get

[image: bg]

what I want

[image: bg2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0` ?

Comment: position in react-native can't take "Fixed" as the value just "relative | absolute" @Yuan-HaoChiang

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to add a full screen background image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322973/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make header transparent for a specific screen by adding property [headertransparent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertransparent)

**Try this**

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    headerTransparent: true,
  };
```

**Complete Sample code**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Home"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text
          style={{ padding: 20 }}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail")}
        >
          Send To Detail
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTransparent: true,
    headerTintColor: "#fff"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: width, height: 400 }}
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/different-types-of-food-on-rustic-wooden-table-picture-id861188910?s=2048x2048",
            cache: "force-cache"
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: DetailScreen
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**App Demo**

[image]

Comment: Great!, But when i wrap this Image in <Safearea> it does not take the full size, That's mean header transparent not deal with safearea?

Comment: @DevAS , You should not use Safearea . React Navigation header take care of surface area . You should start your screen from simple view

Answer (score 1):

use this styling in header 
{ 
  position: 'absolute',
  zIndex: 100,
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  elevation: 0,
  shadowOpacity: 0,
  borderBottomWidth: 0
}

Answer (score 0):

You need hide the header, if you are using react navigation, you can add the *navigationOptions* for add attributes for hide the header, like these lines.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
  };
```